# Code to print kth row of Pascal's Triangle giving overflow

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

I am writing code to print kth row of pascal's triangle. Taking two vectors initially and alternatively calculating the next row in p and q. But this code is giving overflow and I can't figure our why. Please help!

```
vector<int> getRow(int k) {
    vector<int> p, q;
    p.push_back(1);
    q.push_back(1);
    q.push_back(1);
    
    
    for(int i=2;i<=k;i++)
    {
        if(i%2)
        {
            p.clear();
            p.push_back(1);
            for(int j=1;j<i;j++)
                p.push_back(q[j]+q[j-1]);
            p.push_back(1);
        }
        else
        {
            q.clear();
            q.push_back(1);
            for(int j=1;j<i;j++)
                q.push_back(p[j]+p[j-1]);
            q.push_back(1);
        }
    }
    
    if(k%2)
        return p;
    else
        return q;
}
```

Comment: What's the input when it gets overflowed? It seems okay if `k` is 100. https://godbolt.org/z/rxKKPM ; Provide exact error message would help others to answer your question. Also your code WILL overflow if `k` is large enough.

Comment: Just a sidenode: the terms of the pascal triangle can be calculated using [binomial coefficient `a nCk b`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Answer (score 1):

In this line: `q.push_back(p[j] + p[j - 1])`, you are trying to access `j = 1` when you have not this cell. So add another `p.push_back(1)` and it will work.

Or better change the `push_back` before the loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
    p.push_back(1);
    q.push_back(1);
}
```